# Добавить счётчик кликов submit

Tags: php, mysql

Скрипт статистики посещений, на странице есть форма и кнопка submit, как добавить в скрипт счётчик кликов?

```html
function q($v) { return mysql_real_escape_string($v); }
if (empty($error) and !empty($_GET['url']) and !stristr($_GET['url'],"escape(document.URL)")) {
$offset = 0;
@include("offset.php");
$t = time()+3600*$offset;
$day = date("D",$t);
$dt = date("Ymd",$t);
$tm = date("H:i",$t);
$refer = $_GET['ref'];
$lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);
$user = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']." [".$_GET['scr']."]";
$r = parse_url($_GET['url']); 
$req = $r['path'].(!empty($r['query'])?"?".$r['query']:"").(!empty($r['fragment'])?"#".$r['fragment']:"");

if ($ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
{
 if (!stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'],$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) and !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) $ipu .= ", ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; else $ipu = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
 $proxy = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
else { $ipu = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; $proxy = ""; }
if ($proxy == $ipu) $proxy = "";
$a = explode(", ",$ipu); $real_ipu = $a[count($a)-1];
if (!empty($proxy)) $host = gethostbyaddr($proxy); else if ($host = gethostbyaddr($ipu)) ; else if ($host = gethostbyaddr($real_ipu)) ; else $host = $ipu;

$fri = mysql_query("INSERT INTO skinb(day,dt,tm,refer,ipu,proxy,host,lang,user,req,city,country) VALUES('".$day."','".$dt."','".$tm."','".q($refer)."','".q($ipu)."','".$proxy."','".$host."','".q($lang)."','".q($user)."','".q($req)."')");
if (!$fri) error_log(strftime("%d.%m.%y %H:%M:%S")." Error: ".mysql_error()."\n", 3, preg_replace("/[^\/]+$/i","",__FILE__)."errors.dat");
mysql_close();
}

?>
```

Comment: Отфармотируйте код для начала. Он нечитаем.

Answer (score 0):

//Вытягиваете в переменную текущее значение счетчика из БД

$counter = mysql_query("SELECT count FROM skinb");

//Добавляете 1

$counter++;

//В запросе на запись обновляете значение count

```
 $fri = mysql_query("INSERT INTO skinb(day,dt,tm,refer,ipu,proxy,host,lang,user,req,city,country,count) VALUES('".$day."','".$dt."','".$tm."','".q($refer)."','".q($ipu)."','".$proxy."','".$host."','".q($lang)."','".q($user)."','".q($req)."','".q($counter)."')");
```

Хотя зачем писать велосипед, если в той же яндекс метрике, есть счетчик на кнопку)

Comment: Спасибо! Работает.

Comment: @ivanov отметьте вопрос решенным тогда